Android studio 24.1.1: window 11: Error running app, The emulator process for AVD Pixel_8_Pro_Api_35 terminated
I couldn't find a solution. Can someone help me to understand the issue and fix it?
I am attaching log files also
2024-08-12 11:53:29,304 [ 448484]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=test4, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=C:\Users\Public\App_Development\test4)UnlinkedProjectNotification took 20 ms, XDebuggerManager took 38 ms
2024-08-12 11:53:29,316 [ 448496]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appGradleJvmSupportMatrix took 16 ms, ManagedVirtualDeviceCatalogService took 25 ms
2024-08-12 12:39:37,682 [3216862]   INFO - #c.i.o.v.n.p.FSRecords - Checking VFS started
2024-08-12 12:39:41,818 [3220998]   INFO - #c.i.o.v.n.p.FSRecords - Checking VFS finished (healthy): VFSHealthCheckReport[healthy: true](FileRecordsReport[recordsChecked=262763, recordsDeleted=156855, childrenChecked=105467]{nullNameIds=0, unresolvableNameIds=0, notNullContentIds=211, unresolvableContentIds=0, unresolvableAttributesIds=0, nullParents=0, inconsistentParentChildRelationships=0, generalErrors=0), RootsReport(rootsCount=440, rootsWithParents=0, rootsDeletedButNotRemoved=0, generalErrors=0), NamesEnumeratorReport(namesChecked=167238, namesResolvedToNull=0, idsResolvedToNull=0, inconsistentNames=0, generalErrors=0), ContentEnumeratorReport(contentRecordsChecked=127041, generalErrors=0)){timeTaken=4.119079100s}
2024-08-12 12:41:01,298 [3300478]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-08-12 12:41:01,299 [3300479]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity to files
2024-08-12 12:41:01,329 [3300509]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=MyApplication3, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=C:\Users\Public\App_Development\MyApplication3)RunManager took 11 ms
2024-08-12 12:41:01,340 [3300520]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appGit.Application.Settings took 11 ms
2024-08-12 12:41:01,347 [3300527]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=test4, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=C:\Users\Public\App_Development\test4)GradleLocalSettings took 15 ms
2024-08-12 12:41:18,695 [3317875]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-08-12 12:41:18,696 [3317876]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity to files
2024-08-12 12:41:18,735 [3317915]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=test4, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=C:\Users\Public\App_Development\test4)KotlinCommonCompilerArguments took 19 ms
2024-08-12 12:41:38,317 [3337497]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-08-12 12:41:38,321 [3337501]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity to files
2024-08-12 12:42:49,787 [3408967]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidDeviceSpec - Creating spec for Pixel 8 Pro API 35 with ABIs: [x86_64]
2024-08-12 12:42:49,787 [3408967]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidDeviceSpec - Creating spec for device without privacy sandbox support.
2024-08-12 12:42:49,787 [3408967]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - About to execute Gradle tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
2024-08-12 12:42:49,813 [3408993]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
2024-08-12 12:42:49,845 [3409025]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Build command line options: [--continue, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, -Pandroid.studio.version=241.18034.62.2411.12169540, -Pandroid.injected.attribution.file.location=C:\Users\Public\App_Development\test4\.gradle]
2024-08-12 12:42:49,899 [3409079]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.s.e.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line to Gradle Tooling API: -Pandroid.injected.enableStableIds=true -Pandroid.injected.build.api=35 -Pandroid.injected.build.abi=x86_64 --stacktrace --continue -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.studio.version=241.18034.62.2411.12169540 -Pandroid.injected.attribution.file.location=C:\Users\Public\App_Development\test4\.gradle -Didea.active=true -Didea.version=2024.1 -Didea.vendor.name=Google
2024-08-12 12:42:50,637 [3409817]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 35 - C:\Users\91867\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_8_Pro_API_35 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
2024-08-12 12:42:50,783 [3409963]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 35 - [14172:8252:20240812,124250.783:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\91867\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db\attachments\ce72b97a-306d-44b3-a8f6-c18573e60d69: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-08-12 12:42:50,790 [3409970]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 35 - Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\91867\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db, detection is enabled for process: 17868
2024-08-12 12:42:50,790 [3409970]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 35 - Android emulator version 34.2.16.0 (build_id 12038310) (CL:N/A)
2024-08-12 12:42:50,790 [3409970]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 35 - Found systemPath C:\Users\91867\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-35\google_apis_playstore_ps16k\x86_64\
2024-08-12 12:42:51,379 [3410559]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 35 - [20272:16852:20240812,124251.379:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\91867\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db\attachments\ce72b97a-306d-44b3-a8f6-c18573e60d69: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-08-12 12:42:51,473 [3410653]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 35 - Ignore IPv6 address: 98bd:ec2e:6201:0:908f:ec2e:6201:0 (2x)
2024-08-12 12:42:51,473 [3410653]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 35 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\91867\.android\avd\..\avd\Pixel_8_Pro_API_35.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2024-08-12 12:42:52,318 [3411498]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
2024-08-12 12:42:52,349 [3411529]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Couldn't get post build models.
2024-08-12 12:42:52,349 [3411529]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Gradle invocation complete, build result = com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.AssembleInvocationResult@130451d6
2024-08-12 12:42:52,392 [3411572]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Gradle build finished in 2 s 561 ms
2024-08-12 12:42:52,404 [3411584]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
2024-08-12 12:42:52,890 [3412070]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 35 - added library vulkan-1.dll
2024-08-12 12:42:53,826 [3413006]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 35 - [20272:16852:20240812,124253.826:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\91867\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db\attachments\4b0d16f4-e322-4a02-acfb-be9256d95ff8: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-08-12 12:42:53,826 [3413006]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 35 - [20272:16852:20240812,124253.826:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\91867\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db\attachments\4b0d16f4-e322-4a02-acfb-be9256d95ff8: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-08-12 12:42:53,826 [3413006]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 35 - [20272:16852:20240812,124253.826:ERROR directory_reader_win.cc:43] FindFirstFile: The system cannot find the path specified. (3)
2024-08-12 12:42:58,441 [3417621]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 35 - [20272:16852:20240812,124258.441:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\91867\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db\attachments\4b0d16f4-e322-4a02-acfb-be9256d95ff8: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-08-12 12:42:58,456 [3417636]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 35 - Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
2024-08-12 12:42:58,456 [3417636]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 35 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741819
2024-08-12 12:42:58,696 [3417876]   INFO - #c.i.e.r.ExecutionUtil - Error running 'app':<br>The emulator process for AVD Pixel_8_Pro_API_35 has terminated.
com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_8_Pro_API_35 has terminated.
    at com.android.tools.idea.execution.common.AndroidConfigurationProgramRunner$execute$5.run(AndroidConfigurationProgramRunner.kt:135)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:477)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:133)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsynchronously$6(CoreProgressManager.java:528)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:250)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$0(ProgressManager.java:100)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:221)
    at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.helpers.TraceKt.use(trace.kt:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$13(CoreProgressManager.java:660)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:735)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:691)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:659)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:202)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.runProcess(ProgressManager.java:100)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$5(ProgressRunner.java:250)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner$ProgressRunnable.run(ProgressRunner.java:500)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ChildContext$runAsCoroutine$1.invoke(propagation.kt:81)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ChildContext$runAsCoroutine$1.invoke(propagation.kt:81)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ChildContext.runAsCoroutine(propagation.kt:86)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ChildContext.runAsCoroutine(propagation.kt:81)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$launchTask$18(ProgressRunner.java:466)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$EmulatorTerminatedException: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_8_Pro_API_35 has terminated.
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$WaitForEmulatorTask.run(EmulatorConnectionListener.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder$executeOnPooledThread$1.run(RwLockHolder.kt:154)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    ... 7 more
2024-08-12 12:43:06,367 [3425547]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-08-12 12:43:06,369 [3425549]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity to files
2024-08-12 12:43:06,386 [3425566]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=test4, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=C:\Users\Public\App_Development\test4)DependencyValidationManager took 15 ms
2024-08-12 12:43:06,386 [3425566]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appFileTypeManager took 17 ms

I did try some of suggestions provided in youtube videos such as:

clearing the memory
updating exclusion list
enabling/disabling hyper driver in turn window feature on -off options
there is NO hyper-V options in my PC
deleting all the data and installing from sratch again but still face same issue.
installed JAVA but that did not help

Please someone check for the error in above logs and let me if it is relevant here. also please suggest me the solutions for this.

It may help if you [edit] your question and post a [mcve].

What folders have you deleted when you did "deleting all the data"? Have you also cleaned user temp folder and .android dir in user home (both are mentioned with errors in your posted log)?
